# Does FormsAuthenticationTicket.Name have to be unique?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

Typically I use the user's email address (unique) but in my current project it would be more beneficial to have the users full name (not unique) available from User.Identity.Name.

So does it really matter what I set for the authentication cookie name?

Note I'm aware I can store additional information in the auth cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can put userName `FormsAuthenticationTicketName` It is not necessarily unique but the ticket you recieve should be store in a cookie with unique name.